# Click a button-doesn't post data (Ajax)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to post description of movies, with ajax. I have some movies and for each movie a button with id  "button_id", when I click this button I get the description of the movie. The problem is that I am getting the description only for the first movie. When I click over the button of another movie it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
var id = $('#form_index input[name=id]').val(); 
$('#button_'+id).click(function() {  
        $.ajax({
            url: 'description.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            id: id
        }, 
            success: function (result) {
              $('#more_content').html(result);
            }
        });  

<?php foreach ($positions as $p):?>    
<div id="more_content"></div>
       <form id="form_index" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$p["id"]?>" />                                 
       </form>                          
    <button id="button_<?=$p["id"]?>">Me shume<button>
<?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you add function with  button using "this" parameter,here is my coding try this:

```
function send_movie_name(movie_name) {

    var movie=movie_name.id;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'description.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id:movie}, 
        success: function (result) {
          $('#more_content').html(result);
        }
    });  

    <div id="more_content"></div>
    <form id="form_index" method="post" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value= <?=$p["id"]?>"/>                                       
   </form>                          
    <button id="button_<?=$p['id']?>" onclick="send_movie_name(this)">Me shume<button>
```

**Description**

```
I add one function with your button called
```

> send_movie_name(movie_name)

where movie_name parameter represent *this* which we used to send the different id every time.

In the ajax data pass I change id:id to id:movie where movie contains the id/movie name.

Hope it will work

thank you

chinmoy

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop will create no. of forms, all of them have the same id " form_index " which is wrong.

Comment: So what can I do? How can I take different id's for form ?